# Switch to another popup window in selenium - python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to Switch to another window to close it however i am unable to do it. I have added explicit wait so that the close button can appear and then i can close it
I thought it must be iframe but it is not need a help on this
Below is the screen shot and code for it
The main code which i have implemented is on the last line
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egQ2j.jpg)

Below is code

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='No, thanks!']").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Progress Bars & Sliders").click
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(300, 500)")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Progress Bars & Sliders").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("JQuery Download Progress bars").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='downloadButton']").click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@type='Close']")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='Close']").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong locator `//button[@type='Close']` here:

```py
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@type='Close']")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='Close']").click()
```

It should be `//button[text()='Close']`.
So instead of the above try this:

```py
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Close']"))).click()
```

The entire code will be:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='No, thanks!']").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Progress Bars & Sliders").click
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(300, 500)")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Progress Bars & Sliders").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("JQuery Download Progress bars").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='downloadButton']").click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Close']"))).click()
```

Comment: Thankyou for the help

Comment: You are welcome